# iPhone: "error: ABPerson.h: No such file or directory"... How to use the ABPerson class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm trying to use the ABPerson object. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html) tells me to include ABPerson.h.

Here is basically my code:

```
#import "ABPerson.h"
[...]
-(void) updateImageWithContact:(ABPerson)contact;
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
error: ABPerson.h: No such file or directory
```

I did include Addressbook.framework so I don't know what's going on.

If I remove the #import there is no error, but I can't use the ABPerson class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#import <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>
```

Edit:

1. There's no ABPerson type - all records (for person or group) are of ABRecordRef type - so you should use that
2. Better use     `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`
   and you'll need no extra headers for working with address book
3. To access Address book standard pickers include `<AddressBook/AddressBookUI.h>`

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't break but I still can't use the ABPerson class (I get warnings all over the place).